# How can I get the average likes of a post?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, orm, prisma

I have this model

```
model Post {
  createdAt DateTime       @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime       @updatedAt
  id        String         @id @default(cuid())
  author    UserProfile    @relation("UserProfilePosts", fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  authorId  String
  content   String
  views     Int            @default(0)
  likedBy   UserProfile[]  
  tags      PostTag[]
  comments  Comment[]
}
```

I know I can do something like

```
let queryViews = async () => {
  let query = await prisma.post.aggregate({
    _avg: {
      views: true
    }
  })
  return query._avg.views
}
```

to get the average amount of views for all the posts but for some reason, I can't seem to find any documentation or generated type hints to get the average amount of likes for all the posts. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

We have docs for aggregations [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/aggregation-grouping-summarizing) and here's the sample code:

```
const aggregations = await prisma.user.aggregate({
  _avg: {
    age: true,
  },
})

console.log('Average age:' + aggregations._avg.age)
```

We have a search bar in the docs where searching for the term `aggregate` should lead you to this page.